# Importing .java files on to a Java Project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a Java project in Eclipse that outputs a bunch of text/numbers on to an excel file. I am using a bunch of quickTapSurvey .java files for the project. QuickTapSurvey is just a survey app where users can add/modify the questions according to their needs. I imported the .java files by right clicking on the "default package" and then clicking on the "File system" category. Now that I have all the .java files in my project, they have red "X" marks next to their names, which I am assuming denotes an error (look at the attached snapshots). The code itself has red underlines everywhere. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

List of imported .java files. note the x marks:

[image: List of imported .java files. note the x marks]

Imported files at the top of the  main program:

[image: Imported files at the top of the main program]

Comment: where are the attached snapshots

Comment: Open a file and there will be red indicators showing the code positions where the actual errors are. Eclipse will show tooltips with an error message there. What do the messages say?

Comment: How should we know what's wrong without the code? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your java files reference classes that Eclipse does not know about (they are not found in the classpath). These missing classes are probably related to quickTapSurvey; read their documentation to see how to fix this.